# How to navigate from one page to another in Windows phone 8 using XAML?

Tags: xaml, navigation, windows-phone-8

I am trying to make my first WP8 app but, i got a problem. I try to navigate to another page using the code below, but VS12 throws a error.

What am I doing wrong?

```
private void btnBMIBereken_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/BMI_Bereken.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
```

Comment: What does the error say? Compile or runtime time error?

Comment: I think a runtime error. when i click on a button it goes to : Debugger.Break();

Comment: What is the error that is being displayed in the Error-Dialog?

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll

Comment: It's like he don't recocnize the navigation function

Comment: What are the exception Message or the details? Usually it gives you more information than just the Exception type

Comment: it gives me only that, i have no idea how i can get more error messages

Comment: any ideas how i can let navigation work>??? or do you have some code examples of navigating in the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys i found the problem.

I use a self made button style for my buttons and i got on the visualstate pressed some wrong code. In fact I was trying to set the background collor of the button in the place of the name target name.
See the code below for what i did wrong.

```
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="#FF009AD3">
```

I know very stupid, but I want to thank everyone for the help.

Comment: Good to hear that you've found your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct for navigating, just make sure the Page 'BMI_Bereken.xaml' actual exists at the root of your project.

Comment: yes it exists but stil don't work. i have no idea what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

Clean solution first and then rebuild again (right click on project/solution -> clean)

Then if it still crashes, try to use `System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs` e instead of `RoutedEventArgs e`

Comment: Try to create new solution with two pages and simple button on first. Just to check if its work at all. Anyway if you want to JUST navigate without sending any parameters you can always open your solution in Blend. Right click on your button and you will see 'navigate to' with list of your pages. Remember to delete click event and click handler before that. Still that is bad solution if you want to develop smth more advanced in future.

Comment: What was the fault, @apero

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  private void btnBMIBereken_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/BMI_Bereken.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (txtDriverId.Text == "D0001" && txtPassword.Password == "open")
    {
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(VehicleCondition));
    }
}
```